# Dragging recurring Calendar event from all day to a time slot does not change entire series

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, microsoft-office-2013

We currently are on Office 2013 with server side on 2013 Exchange as well. This question is on behalf of a staff member we support.

She explained that in the the past they were able to drag an all-day, reoccurring event from the top area of the "Day View" in to a time slot below and it would remain there until moved back to the top.

In the current client, when an event is dragged down it only effects that day, and the remaining re-occurrences are still in the all-day section.

Please see these images for an example: [example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UKFI.jpg)

So the goal here is that when the event is dragged from all-day, it stays that way until dragged back. Again, this used to be a feature but no longer works.

Comment: Which mail client/version was being used "in the past"?

Comment: According to her, it was the same version of Office (2013), but another technician told her that an update caused it to stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've used Outlook 2013, All Day events are at the top. Partial day events fit within the start and end time. If you drag an all day event to the bottom portion of the map, it stops being an all day event and becomes a half hour event (if your default is half hour increments). If you have a daily recurring event, just the day you move from all-day to partial day will move -- although that changed event time is still associated with the entire series.

Perhaps she is telling you the truth but in a non-standard view or layout of Outlook. Observe her actions as a one-on-one visit and see if you can reproduce it.

For me, as a workaround on recurring all day events, I just:

- Double click on the calendar entry.
- When asked, select **Just this one** instead of Entire series
- Make your change to the recurring event

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately she can't show me the process happening since it no longer works, but I'll just chalk this one up to Outlook mysteries and let her know the only alternatives.